# Not Unique Table

Tags: mysql

Here's a query, i'm getting this error #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'detail_penerbangan' 
I have 6 Table 
Table 1 penerbangan 
Table 2 sdm 
Table 3 pesawat
Table 4 Type Pesawat 
Table 5 detail_penerbangan
Table 6 area

```
SELECT penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, penerbangan.kd_regispesawat, penerbangan.nrp,penerbangan.misi, penerbangan.status_penerbangan, sdm.nrp, sdm.nama_personel, pesawat.kd_regispesawat, pesawat.kd_typepesawat, type_pesawat.kd_typepesawat,type_pesawat.typepesawat,detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_area_from,area.kd_area, area.singkatan_area
from penerbangan
LEFT JOIN sdm ON penerbangan.nrp = sdm.nrp
LEFT JOIN pesawat ON penerbangan.kd_regispesawat = pesawat.kd_regispesawat
LEFT JOIN type_pesawat ON pesawat.kd_typepesawat = type_pesawat.kd_typepesawat
LEFT JOIN detail_penerbangan ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan
LEFT JOIN area ON detail_penerbangan.kd_area_from = area.kd_area
LEFT JOIN (SELECT penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_area_tujuan, area.kd_area, area.singkatan_area FROM penerbangan, detail_penerbangan
LEFT JOIN detail_penerbangan ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan
LEFT JOIN area ON detail_penerbangan.kd_area_tujuan = area.kd_area
where penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan) 
AS test ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = test.kd_penerbangan
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error #1066 - Not unique table/alias in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328661/error-1066-not-unique-table-alias-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In second subquery you have added the table two times.. one in from with cross join and one with left join that causes this..

Use this..

```
    SELECT penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, penerbangan.kd_regispesawat, penerbangan.nrp,penerbangan.misi, penerbangan.status_penerbangan, sdm.nrp, sdm.nama_personel, pesawat.kd_regispesawat, pesawat.kd_typepesawat, type_pesawat.kd_typepesawat,type_pesawat.typepesawat,detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_area_from,area.kd_area, area.singkatan_area
from penerbangan
LEFT JOIN sdm ON penerbangan.nrp = sdm.nrp
LEFT JOIN pesawat ON penerbangan.kd_regispesawat = pesawat.kd_regispesawat
LEFT JOIN type_pesawat ON pesawat.kd_typepesawat = type_pesawat.kd_typepesawat
LEFT JOIN detail_penerbangan ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan
LEFT JOIN area ON detail_penerbangan.kd_area_from = area.kd_area
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan, detail_penerbangan.kd_area_tujuan, area.kd_area, area.singkatan_area FROM penerbangan LEFT JOIN detail_penerbangan ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan
    LEFT JOIN area ON detail_penerbangan.kd_area_tujuan = area.kd_area
    where penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = detail_penerbangan.kd_penerbangan
) 
AS test ON penerbangan.kd_penerbangan = test.kd_penerbangan
```